app maui .net para android 13 no solicita permisos lectura/escritura
Estoy intentando desarrollar un sistema de log en mi app para que vaya escribiendo en un .txt conforme voy avanzando por sus pantallas. Todo esto con MAUI .NET (net8.0) para un dispositivo con ANDROID 13 -API 33- (la tablet donde depuro), sin indicar destino especifico y como plataforma mínima ANDROID 8.1 (API 27).
En "AndroidManifest.xml" he marcado los permisos "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" y "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".
En lo que respecta al cogido, primero chequeo el estatus de los permisos de lectura y escritura y después pregunto para que el usuario de los permisos necesarios:
                        //leemos el estado de un permiso en particular (unknow, denied, disabled, granted, restricted, limited)
                        PermissionStatus status_read = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
                        PermissionStatus status_write = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

                        //preguntamos para que el usuario conceda los permisos (una vez tiene permiso ya funciona y no vuelve a preguntar)
                        PermissionStatus status_permiso_lectura = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
                        PermissionStatus status_permiso_escritura = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

El caso es que cuando paso por este código, me indica que el acceso está denegado, pero nunca lanza la pregunta de si deseo otorgar permisos.
Igualmente con la app ya instalada en la tablet, si accedo a la información de la app, no me aparece la "lectura/escritura" como permisos "no permitidos".
Exactamente este mismo código y configuración, ejecutados en un dispositivo móvil con Android 8.1.0 me funciona perfectamente. Si ya tiene permisos me permita seguir con mi lectura/escritura. Y si no los tiene me pregunta si quiero otorgarlos.
-------------- EDITO ------------------------------------
Tengo otra app creada de la misma manera en la que la única diferencia es que el "Runtime de .NET de destino" es "net7.0" y esta si que funciona perfectamente. ¿Será ese el problema?

¿Alguien más ha tenido este problema? ¿Me podrían ayudar?
Gracias. Un saludo.

ME parece que tratas de escribir afuera de la estructura de archivos que genera la aplicación, debes recordar que a partir de Android 11, el uso de READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE y WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ya no otorga el acceso completo a la SD Card, solo puedes escribir dentro de la estructura de archivos que genera tu aplicación:
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/

Revisa esta respuesta:
¿Cómo crear carpeta en android 11?

Si deseas escribir en cualquier parte del almacenamiento externo entonces necesitas declarar el permiso MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Declarq el permiso MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE en el manifiesto.
Use la acción de intención ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION para dirigir a los usuarios a una página de configuración del sistema donde pueden habilitar la siguiente opción para su aplicación: Permitir acceso para administrar todos los archivos.

Después de eso, puede guardarlo en la ruta /storage/emulated/0/Documents.
